# Is it possible to backup AWS RDS Aurora MySQL per database by any AWS services?

Tags: mysql, backup, aws-aurora

I have several AWS RDS Aurora clusters, and user data is stored in different database.

Currently I have my own script to backup per database, but I am considering to backup through AWS provided services to provide a higher availability and stability. I tried to look into AWS documents and studied AWS Backup about suggested backup strategies, and they all seem like focusing on backup the whole database instance at once regularly.

So, my question is that does AWS provide any services that allowing backup per database regularly? Or using my own script is the only way?

Comment: Put each of your databases on its own separate Aurora instance.

Comment: @BillKarwin It could be a huge change on current application architecture, which is not an option.